# How to see where the issue in my network is

Tags: networking, router

While I am just browsing on my network, I lose connection for maybe 5 seconds at a time every minute or so. This has become a huge annoyance so I want to figure out what part of my network is the problem. I have a modem connected to a router, which I access from my PC. I ran pings to 8.8.8.8 and 192.168.29.1 simultaneously and while I get `Request timed out` to 8.8.8.8, I am still able to ping my router fine. Does this mean that it is a problem with the modem?

Comment: I'd say so yes, or your ISP

Answer (score 1):

You've identified partially where the problem is located, between the the internet, and the outside of your router.

This could be occuring from 3 points:

1. Your router itself may be having issues, and while your internal routing is fine, something on the external 'side' of the router has gone wrong
2. Your modem is having issues (this is presuming you have a seperate unit from your router.)
3. A problem with your ISP's equipment, or the cable connecting your modem to them.

For the first two, if possible, swap them out for a spare/borrowed one to try and diagnose if there's an issue there. As for the ISP's equipment, it'd be up to them to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off your router and modem for 10 minutes. It may be that the temperature of your router or modem is too high.

In addition, you can use other devices (such as mobile phones) to connect to the network to see if there are any similar problems.

If the problem is the same, this means that the problem is in the router or modem or ISP.